# How many people can you add to an iMessages group?

Tags: ios, messages

I was curious what the limit was on the number of people you can add to an iMessages group. Assuming everyone was on iMessages (i.e. everyone shows up as blue).

Comment: I have sent a group of 3 messages. I have not tried more, I assume it would be limitless as it is just an instant message over an Internet connection. I am interested to find out if anyone has tried. Do we know what the SMS group limit is? As this could be the limit physically set by the app.

Comment: What makes you think there is a limit? (also - it's a bit of social suicide to even find out where the limit is)

Comment: @bmike http://i.imgur.com/I9aLhKC.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read nothing about a limit in the different user guides for iOS devices (e.g. [iPhone User Guide [PDF, 17MB]](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf)). Because of that I think there is **no** limit for groups.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has published on April 03, 2020 a limit of 32 people per group iMessage / Messages / FaceTime. You can have many more groups in the app, just not more than 32 distinct AppleID/iCloud per group.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209022

> You can start a Group FaceTime from the FaceTime app or from a group conversation in the Messages app — and you can add up to 32 people.

Comment: I believe this limit was higher or there was no set limit for chat before Group FaceTime video came about and that was initially limited, announced, in beta, not shipped with the .0 and then rolled out to Mac and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 9 members is the maximum amount that can participate in a single iMessage group thread.

I don't know the reason for this arbitrary number but people in my company have discovered this on their own. We are organized into groups of 12 and have not been able to include the entire group  without a third-party app.

---

With regards to other comments made earlier in this string, there are countless reasons businesses would use group texting in fairly large groups. For example, sales teams, management team, or dept. teams can use messaging for rapid means of communication.

Messaging is quickly becoming the preferred means of communication where I work when rapid responses from groups are required or when everyone is spread out geographically. Email tends to be slower even if it is pushed to users devices. We primarily use email for longer messages and less urgent matters.

Comment: Is that with everyone on iMessage and no one on SMS i.e. the send button is blue?

Comment: Sadly, I've been in groups of 30 or more and when everyone keeps replying, it can make one wish for a temporary block in iMessage or way to opt out of that thread...

Answer (score 0):

I just unsuccessfully did 28 for an event here in Denver.

Comment: Did it come up with any specific error message?